# MS Access Exponential, Dividing and Rounding

Tags: ms-access, exponential

I have a table which has the following:

```
TRANSACTION    RECALCULATED_TRANSACTION    CUSTOMERS     DIFFERENCE     SPLIT
2.01           2.09                        2             0.08           0.05
```

**TRANSACTION** is the value of a customer's transaction
**RECALCULATED_TRANSACTION** is the new transaction amount after it's been through a pretty lengthy calculation (written in VBA)
**CUSTOMERS** is the number of customers per transaction
**DIFFERENCE** is the difference between RECALCULATED_TRANSACTION and TRANSACTION
**SPLIT** is DIFFERENCE divided by CUSTOMERS and rounded up

As you can see in this example, my Access database is giving an output of 0.05 for SPLIT, when it should be 0.04 (0.08 / 2) and I can't work out why. As there is no inbuilt ROUNDUP function in Access, a colleague created a module for me (code below)

One possible cause is because although the DIFFERENCE value is visible as 0.08, when I click into the field in Access, it then changes to 8.00000000000001E-02. Does this mean the actual value that is being stored is greater than 0.08 and explains why when it is divided by 2 and rounded up, SPLIT becomes 0.05?

**ROUNDUP MODULE**

```
Function roundup(X As Double) As Double

    If X > Int(X * 100) / 100 Then
        'turn value into an 100 times then only take the integer value. Add one to increase by 0.01 and
        'divide value by 100 to return back to 2 decimal places
        roundup = (Int(X * 100) + 1) / 100
    
    Else
            roundup = X
        
    End If

    'returns the new value back to the calling function
    
End Function
```

Comment: Yes. The difference is a little bigger than .08. So after dividing by 2 the split is a little bigger than .04. Your roundup function converts it to .05.